# Are the fibers of a group homomorphism the cosets of its kernel?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Given a group $G$ and a homomorphism $f : G \to G'$, $f$ induces a relation on $G$, which we will denote $\sim$. The relation is $g_1\sim g_1$ iff $f(g_1) = f(g_2)$. The fiber of an element $y \in G'$ is $f^{-1}[\{y\}] = \{k\in G\ |\ f(k)=y\}$, so if $e'$ is the identity element in $G'$, then $f^{-1}[\{e'\}] = \ker f$.

Let $f(g) = g'$. Then is $f^{-1}[\{g'\}]=g\ker f$? In other words is
$$
\{gh\ |\ f(h) = e'\} = \{k\ |\ f(k) = f(g)\}?
$$

I'm going in circles and getting confused trying to prove or disprove this. My gut is telling me it should be false, but I have yet to find a counterexample, and everything I've done so far seems to point to it being true. Yet it still feels off.

Here's one thing I attempted to do. If $g\ker f$ are the fibers of $\sim$, then $g_1\ker f$ and $g_2\ker f$ must be disjoint iff $g_1 \not\sim g_2$. If the two sets are not disjoint, this implies that there exists $h_1\in\ker f$ such that there exists $h_2\in\ker f$ satisfying 
$$
\begin{align}
& g_1h_1 = g_2h_2 \\
\implies & g_2^{-1}g_1h_1 = h_2
\end{align}
$$
If $h_2$ exists, then $f(g_2^{-1}g_1h_1)=e'$, which implies that $f(g_2)^{-1}f(g_1) = e'$, or that $f(g_1) = f(g_2)$, implying $g_1\sim g_2$.

This sounds like it should mean $g_1\ker f$ and $g_2\ker f$ are disjoint unless $g_1$ and $g_2$ are in the same fiber, but I used so many logical implications above that I just get confused. If everything I did above is right, then I proved that $(g_1\ker f\ \cap\ g_2\ker f \ne \emptyset)\implies(g_1\sim g_2)$. But that doesn't necessarily mean that $g_1\ker f = g_2\ker f$ if $g_1\sim g_2$, or that $(g_1\not\sim g_2)\implies(g_1\ker f\ \cap\ g_2\ker f = \emptyset)$.

So is this true or false, and how may I prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the first isomorphism theorem (for groups). However to prove directly what you ask for:

Let $f(g) = g'$. Then you want to show that $f^{-1} (g') = g \ker(f)$ (i.e. the pre-image under $f$ of $g'$ should coincide with a left coset of $\ker(f)$).

Let $h \in f^{-1}(g') \subseteq G$, thus $f(h) = g' = f(g)$. Hence $f(g^{-1}h) = 1_{G'}$ thus $g^{-1}h \in \ker(f)$ and so we get $h = (g g^{-1}) h = g (g^{-1} h) \in g \ker(f)$. This gives $f^{-1}(g') \subseteq g \ker(f)$.

Let $ga \in g\ker(f)$. Then $f(ga) = f(g) f(a) = f(g) = g'$. Hence $ga \in f^{-1}(g')$, i.e. $g \ker(f) \subseteq f^{-1}(g')$.